# oracle - getting highest values for each two type

Tags: sql, database, oracle, group-by

let's say this is the table "transcations" :

```
first_type      second_type     value
m               t1              2
a               t2              2
a               t3              2
b               t1              6
g               t4              4
b               t2              2
r               t4              3
m               t4              2
g               t1              2
b               t4              6
a               t4              17
```

how can i select the max value for each 'first_type' while showing associated 'second_type' column, the desired result is :

```
first_type      second_type     value
m               t1              2
b               t1              6
g               t4              4
r               t4              3
m               t4              2
b               t4              6
a               t4              17
```

or keeping just the highest value omitting other rows that have the same value for the 'first_type' column, like this :

```
first_type      second_type     value
m               t1              2
g               t4              4
r               t4              3
b               t4              6
a               t4              17
```

I tried to select the max value while grouping by 'first_type' but I can't select 'second type since Oracle does not permit selecting something not in the group clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a where in with max

```
select first_type, second_type, value 
from my_table 
where ( first_type, value) in (select first_type, max(value)
                                from my_table 
                                group by first_type)
```

Comment: thank you for your response, what id my_table is another select statement  ?

Comment: @youzking  . is the same that my_table  is a real table or a dinamic temp table  ..

Comment: but here my_table is used twice so i have to duplicate the whole select statement (temp data) which require more time and resources

Comment: @youzking  of course you must use the proper code twice or using a view

Answer (score 2):

You want `rank()`:

```
select first_type, second_type, value
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (partition by first_type order by value desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  This uses `rank()` because your data has ties and you want all of them.